# Does using modules cause issues with duplicate resource block names

Tags: terraform

I am working with Terraform and I'm trying to refactor some code to use a private module. The idea of the module is to simplify the process of creating an AWS API Gateway resource and connecting a lambda to the gateway. I want to test this out myself but I only have a live production environment and that's not the place for experimenting!

I plan on having the module take in the necessary resources, names, or information to handle all of this. My question is branching from https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/module-create?in=terraform/modules and after further searching, I couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

If I am to make my own module, do I need to worry about the naming of the resources in the module? For example:

**functions.tf**

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "foo_function_storage_upload" {
  bucket = var.dev_bucket_id
  key    = "lambdas/foo-tf-handler.zip"
  source = data.archive_file.foo_function_source.output_path
  etag   = filemd5(data.archive_file.foo_function_source.output_path)
}

# Lamda Initialization
resource "aws_lambda_function" "foo_function_handler" {
  function_name = "foo-function-handler"
  description   = "${var.aws_profile}: This is a function"
  s3_bucket     = var.dev_bucket_id
  s3_key        = aws_s3_bucket_object.foo_function_storage_upload.key

  # Entrypoint to lambda function. Format is <file-name>.<property-name>
  handler = "index.handler"
  runtime = "nodejs14.x"
  timeout = 60

  # IAM role for lambda defined below
  role             = var.default_lambda_role_arn
  publish          = true
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.foo_function_source.output_path)
}

# Give permission to the API gateway to access this lambda
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "foo_api_gateway" {
  # Name of lambda from above
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.foo_function_handler.arn
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  # Link to execution arn of API Gateway REST API
  # The "/*/*" portion grants access to any method, any resource within API Gateway
  source_arn = "${var.api_gateway_arn}/*/*"
}
```

**api.tf**

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "foo_get_method" {
  # ID of the REST API and the resource at which the API is invoked
  rest_api_id      = aws_api_gateway_resource.foo_resource.rest_api_id
  resource_id      = aws_api_gateway_resource.foo_resource.id
  http_method      = "GET"
  authorization    = "NONE"
  api_key_required = true
}

# Integration between API Gateway and lambda function
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "foo_get_method_lambda_api_integration" {
  # ID of the REST API and the endpoint at which to integrate a lambda function
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_method.foo_get_method.rest_api_id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.foo_get_method.resource_id

  # ID of the HTTP method at which to integrate with the lambda function
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.foo_get_method.http_method

  # Lambdas can only be invoked via HTTP POST
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"

  # The URI at which the API is invoked
  uri = aws_lambda_function.foo_function_handler.invoke_arn
}
```

Can I just have this generic set up and provide the module with needed information such as the path to the lambda, `aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_id`, `aws_gateway_resource.id`, and maybe a function name?
Will a problem arise due to the naming of the resources? i.e I use the module three times for three separate lambdas connected to gateway endpoints. Does `foo_function_storage_upload` or `foo_function_handler` have to be unique?

Comment: Not sure I understand what do you mean by "unique", but resources, even when being created with modules, do have to have unique names. Having said that, if you invoke a module a couple of times and name it differently should work as long as the real resource name is distinct from other resources.

Comment: For example, leaving `function_name = "foo-function-handler"` across module calls will cause an error. However, you could use a variable to provide a different name across module calls and make the function name unique.

Comment: @MarkoE the function_name = "foo-function-handler" is one of the variables I would provide. I am wondering if from the multiple modules, if having resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "foo_get_method" would cause an error since each module would have resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "foo_get_method" For more reference, I would have `module "example1" { source = "./modules/create_aws_gateway_with_lambda" variables = {...} }` and `module "example2" { source = "./modules/create_aws_gateway_with_lambda" variables = {...} }`

Comment: It shouldn't as long as the real name of the resource is different across module calls.